# how can I create a Event trigger for when leaving a textbox that is Inside a List view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a list View with two Textbox and a label. I want to create a event trigger for one textbox. So when the user leaves the textbox it changes the label on the same row. I have been looking for a answer but I can't find it. Any help would be appreciated

.Aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource2">
<LayoutTemplate>
<table cellpadding="2" width="640px" border="1" runat="server" id="tblProducts">
        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
          <th id="Th1" runat="server">EmployeeID</th>
          <th id="Th2" runat="server">Name</th>
          <th id="Th3" runat="server">Absentee Code</th>
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
</table>    
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<tr runat="server">
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>    
</ItemTemplate>        
</asp:ListView>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/EmptyRows.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<div style="height: 36px">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submitt" />
</div>
```

.VB this is what I was trying but it doesnt work

```
    Protected Sub ListView1_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As ListViewCommandEventArgs)
    Dim textbox1 As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1")


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use jquery/javascript to do this?

Comment: If I use Jquery would I be able to know on what column I am. Example If I'am on row1 and leaving the text box I want to change the label on the same row. It should work like this for every row